# Lipschitz continuous function | Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

> Let $a, \space b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a < b$ and consider $f:[a,b] \rightarrow
>  \mathbb{R}$ s.t $f$ is continuous at $[a, b]$ and Lipschitz continuous
> at $(a, b)$.  Does it necessarily imply $f$ is Lipschitz continuous
> at $[a, b]$?

Although this seems obviously true, I don't see how I can prove it using $f$ continuity. I'd like if someone can guide me to develop some intuition, .e.g, providing a specific case of this property.

Thanks!

Comment: **Hint :** write $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq L|x-y|$ and take the limit as $x$ tends to $a$ and $y$ tends to $b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $L$ be a Lipschitz constant for $f$ on $(a,b)$. Take $x\in(a,b)$. Let $\varepsilon>0$, and use the continuity of $f$ to choose a $\delta>0$ such that

$$\lvert f(a)-f(\xi)\rvert\leq\varepsilon$$

for all $\xi\in(a,a+\delta]$. Then, for any $\xi\in(a,a+\delta]$,

$$\lvert f(a)-f(x)\rvert\leq\lvert f(a)-f(\xi)\rvert+\lvert f(\xi)-f(x)\rvert\leq\varepsilon+L\lvert \xi-x\rvert.$$

Letting $\xi\downarrow a$ we get that

$$\lvert f(a)-f(x)\rvert\leq L\lvert a-x\rvert+\varepsilon.$$

As $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary,

$$\lvert f(a)-f(x)\rvert\leq L\lvert a-x\rvert.$$

A similar argument can be used for the remaining case.

Answer (score 0):

Say that you have
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|\le L|x-y|\quad\text{for $x,y\in(a,b)$.}
$$
Since $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, letting $x\to a$ or $y\to b$ you also have
$$
|f(a)-f(y)|\le L|a-y|\quad\text{for $y\in(a,b)$}
$$
and
$$
|f(b)-f(y)|\le L|a-y|\quad\text{for $y\in(a,b)$}.
$$
Finally, again since $f$ is continous, letting $y\to b$ in the first or letting $y\to a$ in the second you also get
$$
|f(a)-f(b)|\le L|a-b|.
$$